# How to autowire JpaRepository<T,Integer> using generic class

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I want to make Single repository like

```
public  class GenericRepo<T>
{

    @Autowired
    JpaRepository<T, Integer>jpaRepository;

    @Transactional
    public List<T> findAll() {
        List<T>lists=null;
        if(jpaRepository!=null)
        {
            lists= jpaRepository.findAll();
        }

        return lists;
    }
}



GenericRepo<Place> genericRepo=new GenericRepo<Place>();
genericRepo.findAll();

GenericRepo<User> genericRepo=new GenericRepo<User>();
genericRepo.findAll();
```

User and Place are entities in my project.

when I call above methods

it gives NullpointerException

Comment: You seem to be managing instances of `GenericRepo` on your own with 'new'. You need to make those beans managed by Spring for starters

Comment: I am not talking about interfaces. I am talking about the instances themselves. You are creating instances using new, which means that they are not managed by Spring, and therefore cannot be candidates for autowiring

Comment: @geoand I just want to avoid Defining interface for each entity in my application e.g. interface UserRepo extends JpaRepository<User,Integer> and interface PlaceRepo extends JpaRepository<Place,Integer> instead of this I want make one common repository for all my entities.How can I achiev that??